# JPA entity with join column but not persisted

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have to entities

```
    @Table(name = "BD_PERSON")
    public class DBPerson {
      @Id
      @Column(name = "persion_id")
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      private Long id;
      
      @Column(name = "name")
      private String name;
    
      @Column(name = "car_id")
      private Long car_id;
    
      @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
      @JoinColumn(name = "car_id", referencedColumnName = "car_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
      private DBCar car;
    
      @Column(name = "label")
      private String label;
```

and

```
@Table(name = "BD_CAR")
public class DBCar {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "car_id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "car_number")
  private Integer carNumber;

  @Column(name = "description")
  private String description;
```

I want to be able to get the Person with the car entity but this should not persist to the database when updating.
But i should be able to update the car_id by itself as it relates the the id in the car table.

but when i try to test this by setting only the car_id i receive an Referential integrity constraint violation.
Because the car_id (FK)references the car_id (PK)
Is there any better way to accomplish what im trying to do?
The database already exists and is configured like this where the car_id is not an actual foreign key

Comment: IMHO the mapping is correct. How do you try to save Car an Person?

Comment: i try to just save a car via its own carrepository.save(car) and i try to do the same with the personrepository.save(person) but in the latter only giving the car_id allong in the model.

I have tried to save the car by adding it to the person model but then when i try to get the car_id from the person model it remains null

Comment: And you set car_id in Person, right?

Comment: in the first version yes, when saving the seperatly via their own repositories in the second version when doing it all via the person repository i dont explicitly set the id but give the whole car with the person but then the person.car_id stays null

Comment: But the car is readonly! So you have to set the car_id

Comment: yes i know but that still delivers a constraint exception on the setting of the car_id

Comment: Set the Hibernate loggers and check the SQL: logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=trace